# how to show selected user to view mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this code showing all MySQL table data to any users but i want only admin and user to show data of mysql query

i have multiple users

```
1.admin 
2.user123 
3.xyz
```

so i want only admin and user to show MySQL table data how can i do this

example
if admin and user123 open the page then mysql data showing correct if xyz user open the page then it will not showing any data

```
user login name <?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']; ?>
```

i want to add this one in to mysql query to showing result only admin and user

```
          $query = "SELECT * FROM `follower` WHERE `followername` LIKE '".$letter."%' ORDER BY `followername` ASC LIMIT $from, $max_results";
```

complete code

```
<?php
$max_results = 10;
$from = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results);


if(empty($_POST)) {
              $query = "SELECT * FROM `follower` WHERE `followername` LIKE '".$letter."%' ORDER BY `followername` ASC LIMIT $from, $max_results";
} 
$result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); //the main trick
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<table class='gridtable' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Company Name</th><th>Mobile No</th></tr>";

if ($rows > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row['followername'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row['companyname'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row['mobileno'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['contractdatee'];
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }
} else {
        echo "<tr><td align=\"center\" colspan=\"4\">No results found!</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

// Figure out the total number of results in DB: 
$total_results = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as followername FROM follower ORDER BY followername ASC"),0);

// Figure out the total number of pages. Always round up using ceil() 
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $max_results);

// Build Page Number Hyperlinks 
echo "<p class=\"style2\">Pages: ";

// Build Previous Link 
if($page > 1){ 
$prev = ($page - 1); 
echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['php_SELF']."?page=$prev&letter=$letter\" class=\"style2\">Previous</a> "; 
}

for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++){ 
if(($page) == $i){ 
echo "$i "; 
} else { 
echo " "; 
} 
}


// Build Next Link 
if($page < $total_pages){ 
$next = ($page + 1); 
echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['php_SELF']."?page=$next&letter=$letter\" class=\"style2\">Next</a>"; 
} 
echo "</p>";

mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Check if user is valid in your PHP code and then show data accordingly. Best is to use Database for user roles and permissions.

Comment: but how can i add user role and permissions in this code

Comment: What's your problem here? Just check for the logged in user id and retrieve data accordingly.

Comment: Permissions: This is something you have to configure on your database server e.g. via phpmyadmin or such tools -- or rethink your logic behind that need.